# Weblogic, Spring, jaxb2-marshaller

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, weblogic

I try to Google this, and search on stack, but unsuccessfully. I found similar topics, but there are no right answer for me.
On deploy my java application to weblogic 12c, i got an error like this:

```
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1443454364203> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1573176327492941" for task "24". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 62; columnNumber: 43; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'."
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 62; columnNumber: 43; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'.
```

My jms-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
<!-- a lot of beans -->
    <bean id="oxmMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="ru.beeline.sdp.service.a2p_template_provisioningservice.smstemplate.TData" />
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
</beans>
```

In my pom.xml:

```
    <spring-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to schema location rules on [w3cshcools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp) i have wrong context.

Right context is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
```

Comment: I believe you were just missing the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm` schemaLocation.